# Match clause doesn't work in XSLT when matching SVG tags

Tags: xslt

I have a rather simple XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="svg">
        <svg>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        </svg>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="circle">
        <xsl:copy-of select='.'/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The goal is to take an SVG file akin to

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="200" height="250" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <rect x="10" y="10" width="30" height="30" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>

    <circle cx="25" cy="75" r="20" stroke="red" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>
    <ellipse cx="75" cy="75" rx="20" ry="5" stroke="red" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>

    <line x1="10" x2="50" y1="110" y2="150" stroke="orange" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>
    <polyline points="60 110 65 120 70 115 75 130 80 125 85 140 90 135 95 150 100 145"
              stroke="orange" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>

    <polygon points="50 160 55 180 70 180 60 190 65 205 50 195 35 205 40 190 30 180 45 180"
             stroke="green" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>

    <circle cx="35" cy="75" r="20" stroke="red" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>

    <path d="M20,230 Q40,205 50,230 T90,230" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5"/>
</svg>
```

and produce

```
<svg>
   <circle cx="25" cy="75" r="20" stroke="red" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>
   <circle cx="35" cy="75" r="20" stroke="red" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"/>
</svg>
```

In other words i want an SVG containing only the circles of this image.

For some reason `match` clause doesn't seem to work. I have tried substituting `match="svg"` with `match="/"`, and that has successfully produced an `<svg>` tag, but it was empty, since no circles are getting matched.

In all likelihood, this is something very simple that i'm missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic reason your script failed (templates don't match) is that:

- the tag names in your source file are actually in
  `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` namespace,
- but you try to refer to them **without** any namespace.

To make your matching correct, you must:

- add `xmlns:sv="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` to the `stylesheet` tag,
- prefix tag names with `sv:`.

Another changes:

- Add `exclude-result-prefixes="sv"` to prevent adding namespace to
  the main output tag.
- Add *identity template* to automatically copy required content.
- Add `select="sv:circle"` to `apply-templates` in template matching `svn`,
  to limit processing of child content to just `circle` tags.

I also changed the template matching `circle`. The reason is to create
**own** `circle` tag (with no namespace), like you did in the template
matching `svg`.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:sv="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  exclude-result-prefixes="sv">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="sv:svg">
    <svg>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="sv:circle"/>
    </svg>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sv:circle">
    <circle>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </circle>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```